# Roblox: Attempt to index nil with "Backpack"

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a script on Roblox for a pickaxe that gives ore to the player, but I'm getting an error and nothing's happening. The code is in a local script inside a tool being held by the player. Below is my code:

```
local tool = script.Parent
local canMine = false

local PS = game:GetService("Players")

local function onTouch(otherPart, player, name)
    local oreTier = otherPart:WaitForChild("OreTier").Value
    local gold = otherPart:FindFirstChild("Gold").Value
    local oreNaame = otherPart:WaitForChild("OreToSpawn").Value
    local toolTier = tool.ToolTier.Value
    if not oreTier then return end

    local oreToSpawn = game.ReplicatedStorage.Items.Resources.Ores:FindFirstChild(oreNaame) 
    
    if oreTier <= toolTier and canMine then
        
        local oreExists = oreToSpawn
        
        print("The ore was hit.")
        
        if oreExists then
            local ore = oreToSpawn:Clone()
            ore.Parent = player.Backpack
            otherPart:Destroy()
        end


        end
    end
--end

local function slash()
    local str = Instance.new("StringValue")
    str.Name = "toolanim"
    str.Value = "Slash" 
    str.Parent = tool
    canMine = true
    tool.Handle.SwordSlash:Play()
end

tool.Activated:Connect(slash)
tool.Pick.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BasePart#Touched

`Touched` only provides the colliding part. `player` and `name` are not used and thus nil. You need to retrieve the player via e.g. the tools parent.

Comment: I replaced "player" with Players.LocalPlayer, and it worked. Thanks for helping out